# How to wait for same browser tab title text with Selenide?

Tags: java, selenium, wait, assertion, selenide

I would like to find out how to make waiter for assertion with window title text in selenide / selenium

something like this:

```
waitUntil(assertion.true(Selenide.title().toLowerCase().startsWith("text")), timeout);
```

may be you could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
{ ...
     await().atMost(timeOut, SECONDS).until(assertionWaitForTitle("text")); 
}

private Callable<Boolean> assertionWaitForTitle(String start) {
     return () -> Selenide.title().toLowerCase().startsWith(start);
}
```